# SQL recursion sample

Tags: sql, recursion

I want to load a dynamic menu using same table containing parent and child nodes.
Table Structure:

```
COMPID | ParentID | MenuName
----------------------------
1      | 1        | Menu 1
2      | 2        | Menu 2
3      | 1        | Menu 3 of Child 1
4      | 1        | Menu 4 of Child 1
5      | 4        | Menu 5 of Child 4 of Child 1
```

There may be more then one technique. But I need to know is it possible using [recursion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to load it dynamically?
If yes then let me have an example.

Comment: are you talking about materialized query tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSI SQL supports recursive queries using a common table expression.

The following retrieves the complete path to each menu item using ANSI SQL:

```
with recursive menu_tree as (
  select compid, parentid, menuname, menuname as menu_path
  from menus
  where compid = parentid -- the root nodes
  union all
  select c.compid, c.parentid, c.menuname, p.menu_path||'/'||c.menuname 
  from menus c
    join menu_tree p 
     on c.parentid = p.compid
    and c.parentid <> c.compid
)
select compid, menu_path
from menu_tree;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fbfba/1

Comment: It should probably be noted that, although this is standard SQL, not every vendor implements it.  Notably MySQL and SQLite (and probably others).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: SQLite *does* support this: http://sqlite.org/lang_with.html Of the "big names" it's only MySQL which does not support this (and many other modern SQL features)

Comment: Huh, you're right.  I wonder what it was I was thinking of instead?  Maybe `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: you are right. SQLite does not support window functions (and neither does MySQL - but that's not a surprise)